# Частотный анализ последовательности битов

Tags: java

Имеется файл с записью типа: 010101010001110010101001. Необходимо провести частотный анализ n-грамм. Т.е какое количество раз встретилась последовательность из 8 битов, 16 битов, 24 битов. 
пример вывода :
01011101 - 3 раз
01111010 - 2
0111101001011101 - 2 раза
Как лучше реализовать ?

Comment: map использовать для хранения, или как он в Java зовется?

Comment: напишите как уже реализовали.

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал вот так реализовать

```
String string = "010101010001110010101001";
int rate = 2;//8,16,24
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
int counter = 0;
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    counter++;
    buffer.append(string.charAt(i));
    if (counter == rate) {
        counter = 0;
        Integer frequency = hashMap.get(buffer.toString());
        hashMap.put(buffer.toString(), frequency == null ? 1 : frequency + 1);
        buffer = new StringBuilder();
    }
}

String[] arrayKey = hashMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
for (int k = 0; k < arrayKey.length; k++) {
    Log.i("log__", " arrayKey[k] - hashMap.get(buffer.toString()) - " + arrayKey[k] + " - " + hashMap.get(arrayKey[k]));
}
```

На выходе

```
I/log__:  arrayKey[k] - hashMap.get(buffer.toString()) - 00 - 2
I/log__:  arrayKey[k] - hashMap.get(buffer.toString()) - 01 - 6
I/log__:  arrayKey[k] - hashMap.get(buffer.toString()) - 10 - 3
I/log__:  arrayKey[k] - hashMap.get(buffer.toString()) - 11 - 1
```